# How fix latexmk configuration to use index style file?

Tags: indexing, latexmk

My index .ist style file is being ignored when I run latexmk with the following script...

```
#!/bin/bash
export TSBIN="$HOME/Library/TeXShop/bin/tslatexmk"
export LTMKBIN="$HOME/Library/TeXShop/bin/tslatexmk"
export LTMKEDIT="$HOME/Library/TeXShop/bin"
# make sure latexmkrcedit exists in bin
if [ ! -e "${LTMKEDIT}/latexmkrcedit" ] ; then
    cp "${TSBIN}/latexmkrcDONTedit" "${LTMKEDIT}/latexmkrcedit"
fi
# Use local rc file platexmkrc if it exists. p = project
export localrc=""
if [ -e ./platexmkrc ] ; then
    export localrc="-r ./platexmkrc"
fi
"${LTMKBIN}"/latexmk -pdf -r "${LTMKEDIT}/latexmkrcedit" -r "${TSBIN}/pdflatexmkrc" ${localrc} "$1"
```

... where the referenced file `platexmkrc` in the source directory is:

```
add_cus_dep('idx', 'ind', 0, 'makeidx2ind');
         sub makidx2ind {
                       system("makeindex —s '$_[0]'.ist -o '$_[0]'.ind '$_[0]'.idx");
         };
```

The file `latexmkrcedit` referenced in the `latexmk` script consists mainly of commented sample configuration and uncommented `add_cus_dep` sections to handle glossaries and non-default-name indexes, but *no* other mention of `makeindex`.

The source file `styledindex.tex` is:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

Some text here.
\index{apple}\index{apricot}
\index{banana}\index{blackberry}\index{blueberry}
\index{currant}\index{cherry}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

And the index style file `styledindex.ist` is:

```
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "{\\medskip\\hfill\\large\\textsf{\\textbf{"
heading_suffix "}}\\hfill}\\medskip\\nopagebreak\n"
```

Although the index is produced and printed, it does *not* have the A, B, C letter heads of each alphabetic group in the index.

On the other hand, if I just run `latex`, then

```
makeindex -s styledindex.ist styledindex
```

and finally `latex` again, the expected styling *is* applied to the index.

Why is the latexmk configuration not working here?

The latexmk script is an "engine" actually being run from within TeXShop. However, the same result -- ignoring the `.ist` file -- happens if I directly run that script `latexmk` from within the source directory (with no direct use of TeXShop).

Comment: Away from pc, but have you tried just echoing the last line to see exactly what it outputs. Also I do not really understand the complexity of this, is all this really needed? Why are you doing a sys call for makeindex instead of just redefining `$makeindex`?

Comment: @daleif: which "last line" do you suggest I echo?

Comment: @daleif: the "complexity" is to indicate how the local config file `platexmkrc` comes into play.

Comment: The bash script

Comment: Herb Schulz has provided a solution: in the `platexmkrc` file, rather than add a `add_cus_dep` dependency — which cannot work because the call to `makeindex` is built in to TeXShop in another way — instead use in `platexmkrc` the command: `$makeindex = "makeindex -s %R.ist %O -o %D %S";`

Comment: NOTE: The makeindex call is built into latexmk so the usual use of a dependency + rule is not the way to do this but rather by changing the $makeindex variable.